# Chrome Canary - No Response in Network

Tags: angular, api, typescript, installation

I have been working on an angular app for a couple of months now. In order to run the app on my machine, I have the following `launch.json` setup.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
    "name": "Launch Focal Tool",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:4200",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "runtimeExecutable": "C:/Users/oscarrod/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome SxS/Application/chrome.exe",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--allow-file-access-from-files",
        "--user-data-dir",
        "--disable-web-security"
    ]
  }]
}
```

Since a couple of days ago the browser stopped processing the `GET` requests. But the weird part is that when the API returns a boolean the browser is able to process it. Please see the following images.

**1.** The `GetCycle` API call

[image: API call seems to be returning nothing]

**2.** The `HasRestrictedAccess` API call

[image: API call returns <code>true</code>]

**3.** If I try calling the API outside the app, for example directly from the browser it does work.

[image]

**Have anyone had this issue?**

Comment: Having the same issue with React + Spring and Chrome. The body is returned in Firefox and cURL. Have you managed to fix it somehow?

Comment: My error stopped suddenly. I guess it was related to the version I was using back then. Now, I'm using **Google Chrome Version 66.0.3335.1 (Official Build) canary SyzyASan (32-bit)**

Comment: I am still having issues even with that version, but my UI is React, don't know if that matters.

Comment: chrome 99.0.4844.51, written in vue. the same thing still exists. works fine in FF